# SQL: How to get AVG on each day with a single query

Tags: sql

I would like to get the average value of each day. For example, I would like to get 4 instead of getting 3 and 5 on "20130511". How can I do that on a single query? (Not hard code)

```
Select Val from Table 1 where??????????
```

**Table1 :**

```
Date      Val
----------------

20130511 | 3

20130511 | 5

20130512 | 5

20130512 | 1

20130512 | 2

20130512 | 6

20130512 | 2

20130513 | 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the date

```
SELECT Date, AVG(Val) FROM TABLE GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by date and do it in a single pass

```
SELECT DATE, SUM(VALUE)/COUNT(*) AS AVERAGE 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY DATE
```